# How to use Auto-Layout properly in this case?

Tags: ios7, autolayout

I have a UIView and a UITableView. I'm trying to align them in a way so they are sticked to each other. The UIView has a fixed height and I want the UITableView to consume the rest of the horizontal space.

I applied a set of constraints which got me pretty close to what I want to achieve but there's a problem that I don't know how to solve. The layout is OK in the portrait orientation but there's a gap between the two elements in the landscape mode. Please see the screenshots below.

[image: Portrait orientation. There is no gap between the UIView and the UITableView.]

[image: Landscape orientation. The problematic one.]

Here are the constraint setups for the elements.

UITableView: (all constants are set to 0)

[image: Constraint Setup for UITableView]

UIView: (all constants are set to 0 except for Height)

[image: Constraint Setup for UIView]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue of that space appearing above the top cell of a UITableView.

Like yourself, I looked into the constraints and the properties of the table, though the only way I could fix the issue was to delete the UITableView altogether and re-insert it.

Once re-inserted the gap was gone.